# foreach filtering out members already apart of group

Tags: powershell, foreach

```
$GetGroupsFromUser = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $WPFnamelookupbox.Text |
                     Where-Object { $_.Name -like 'G1*' }
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like "G1*"}

foreach ($G in $Groups) {
    if ($GetGroupsFromUser -contains $G) {
    } else {
        $WPFgroups.Items.Add($G.SamAccountName)
    }
}
```

My goal is I want to only show groups that the user is not a member of.

So I made some progress going with the `-contains` operator. In order for `-contains` to work, I need to first create an array, correct?

Comment: so the logic should be. First get all the groups. Then get all the groups which the user is part of. Store both of them separately in a variable. Then whichever is not matching show that one. You can do that in foreach loop

Comment: [`Get-Help about_Comparison_Operators`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators) will be useful here, especially the information regarding the `-in` operator. In general, `Get-Help` is one of the most useful cmdlets you will find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-contains` functions best when you are trying to find a match of an element in an array.

If you are just looking for the groups that matches a filter that a user does *not* already have we can use `-notcontains` inside a where clause as well for this.

```
$groupFilter = "G*"
$user = "user_bagel"
$allFilteredGroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter "name -like '$groupFilter'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name
$userFilteredGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | Where-object{$_.name -like $groupFilter} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name
$allFilteredGroups | Where-Object{$userFilteredGroups -notcontains $_}
```

You don't need to expand the groups names as I have done. You will get *similar* results either way. Since you only wanted to know the names it seemed silly to keep the complete group object. In theory it will also perform faster this way. Setting up variables like `$groupFilter` makes it easier to make changes to your script down the line.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Compare-Object`:

```
$GetGroupsFromUser = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $WPFnamelookupbox.Text | Where-Object {$_.name -like 'G1*' }
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter "name -like 'G1*'"
Compare-Object $Groups $GetGroupsFromUser | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="}
```